# How to invert table in Latex?

Tags: tables

How to get a table in latex which is parallel to the page length (like landscape) and not the page width (like portrait)?

Using package 'booktabs'

Comment: Package `rotating` and `sidewaystable`.

Comment: `\begin{sidewaystable} ... \end{sidewaystable}`  from package `rotating` instead `\begin{table} ...\end{table}`?

Comment: @Zarko yes, `sidewaystable` instead of `table`